# Extract string when from dynamic input where part of the string may not exists

Tags: regex, go

Lets assume I have a string

```
Abc=cde&efg
```

This formula gives me three groups

```
(.*=)(.*)(&.*)
```

But what if input string is dynamic and `&efg` may exists or not? 
When it doesn't above formula will give me nothing.
I need to use this regex in golang and I would like to do it with one regex (if it is possible) without splitting string with `&`.

Comment: Yes, `(.*=)(.*?)(&.*)?$`, or `(.*=)([^&]*)(&.*)?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*=)(.*?)(&.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N36XrP/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*=)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `=` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(&.*)?` - Group 3 (optional): a `&` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you. Especially for explanation. It works. Can you give me an info why beginning and end of line are mandatory? Why it can't work without ...$

Comment: @rainbow Because of the lazy `.*?` part, it must match up to a specific right-hand boundary.